# Use AutoNumber Value as TempVariable in Access

Tags: ms-access, temporary-objects, autonumber

I'm using Microsoft Access, I've got a form with three sub forms in. I want to use an auto number in the first field. Once I start entering data in the first record I'd like the auto number to set a temporary variable to use in the other sub forms. I want to set the other sub forms using the default value=[TempVars]![AUTONUMBER].

I'm only using the Macro Builder and I have a problem that the next field I want to enter data in is a required field and has a mask on it.

So Far I've tried:

```
>GoToControl [AUTONUMBER]

>SetTempVars 
   >Name: AUTONUMBER
   >Expression = [AUTONUMBER]

>GoToControl [Field2]
```

Here my problem is that it won't let me move from field2 without having filled it in. If I take "is required" off, which I don't want to do, it allows me to go back and forth between fields, but then it screws with the masking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying you have a mask on autonumber? Have you used the link child / link master fields?

Comment: Where is this autonumber coming from? Is it a bound form, and in the parent form you're entering data and thus creating a new record (autonumber)?

Comment: @finnuala I don't have a mask on the number. Yes, I've used the child/master link